# How to debug a 404 error on apache server ( lamp )?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, debugging, http-status-code-404, lamp

I came across 404 error a few times and i have difficulties in debugging this kind of problem.

What is the strategy and tools available to analyse such problems (firebug, logs...).

How to differentiate and fix the cause ?

```
page not existing ,wrong path , redirection and rewriting ,server problem ...
```

Answer (score -3):

404 error code means that a file is not found for whatever reason.
Just check that the file exists and that the path you use is right.

You can analyse sent requests and received responses headers and body in your browser's developper console if you want more details about why some request failed.